# Bernoulli's equation's contradiction

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, bernoulli-equation

Using Bernoulli's equation
P    Pressure
p    density
V     velocity of fluid

$$P_1+ \rho gy_1+\frac{1}{2}\rho V_1^2
= P_2+\rho gy_2+\frac{1}{2}\rho V_2^2$$
$$V_1^2-V_2^2 =\left(2g(y_2-y_1) +\frac{2(P_2-P_1)}{p}\right)$$
$$V_1^2-V_2^2 =K$$  (1)
Where K is constant

Using equation of continuity
$$V_1^2(\frac{ A_1}{A_2})^2 = V_2^2$$

Substitution in (1) gives
$$V_1^2(1-(\frac{A_1}{A_2})^2)=K$$
Here as A1 increase V1 increase which is opposite to equation of continuity in which
as A1 increase  V1 decrease.

Help(・へ・)

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics SE. Please, use laTex notation for formulae. It's about writing them in between of dollar symbols, and laTex commands inside. See here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: FGSUZ done. THANKS FOR SUGESTION :)

Comment: The equations are not all rendering correctly and the some of the equations that did render appear to be wrong. Please check carefully your LaTex and equations are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relation is true for A1=A2 only, in essence a varying area must lead in varying a pressure, there you assumed that the change in all external pressures is zero whereas area has changed, which is wrong.

Addendum:
the relation is also true for V1,V2=0 where no change in external pressure causes no flow, any fluid moves from high pressure to low pressure.

Comment: But pressure at a point is pgh .Where is area in this expression.

Comment: The pressure is not just given by $\rho g h$. It also depends on the velocity, per the Bernoulli equation.

Comment: Oh yes I completely forgot when the equation was in front of me. Thanks :-)

Comment: Well the fact that the pressure at a point is p.+pgh is only true for static fluids or those moving with constant velocity/area (you can make sure of this yourself using the equation) otherwise in hydraulics/fluid dynamics the relation is not true at all and you only find pressure using bernoulli's